# How to highlight a polygon or a vertex under the pointer in Python?

Tags: python, mesh, 3d-view, opengl

I am trying to figure out how to highlight a polygon or a vertex that could be under the mouse pointer in Python for 2.80. The highlighting is just a visual indication. I realize that I will be needing to scan for components and draw the shape, but just do not know how.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at these templates:
1) Operator Modal View3d Raycast: With this you will find the polygon of a mesh under the mouse cursor.
2) Operator Modal Draw: This contains an example of using BGL for drawing in 3d view. With this you will be able to draw the edges of the polygon you find from raycast.

Comment: Thanks that sounds useful, I guess it is a good head start.

Comment: I would suggest mentioning that the templates can be found in [blenders text editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/text_editor.html#script-and-templates) and maybe add links to the git repo copies, [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_view3d_raycast.py) and [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/operator_modal_draw.py)